# MongoDB Login By IP?

Tags: mongodb

Is there a way to authenticate a mongodb user login by ip address?  Can't see anything in the docs about this.

In MySQL for example, say database name `userdb` and username `crashoverride` from IP `192.168.1.22`

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES on *.userdb TO crashoverride@192.168.1.22
```

Any way to do similar IP-based authentication with MongoDB?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need bind_ip ? It's set in the mongodb configuration file or startup command

Comment: I'm aware of bind_ip... to listen on a specific IP address. Does nothing for authentication as far as I know. I know I can listen on an IP that only the internal users have access to, but does not restrict one user from logging in as another user. I have one user that only logs in from a specific IP address, and don't want any other host to log in as that user.

Comment: Ok, I get your point, Two types of users, some of them should login directly from a specific IP without auth, some of them can login from any other IP but need password. Is that right? Do you think x509 login is acceptable? [x.509 to auth client](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/configure-x509-client-authentication/) But I remember this feature is only supported by enterprise mongodb.